# Starting systemd service after network-online.target but DNS is still not available

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've got a program that I want to start by `systemd` on boot but only after DNS is available.

The service file depends on `network-online.target`:

```
$ cat  /etc/systemd/system/te-m-pi.service
[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/opt/te-m-pi
ExecStart=/opt/te-m-pi/te-m-pi.py

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

However when it's started it immediately quits because it can't resolve some host names it needs:

```
te-m-pi.py[399]: socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
systemd[1]: te-m-pi.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: Unit te-m-pi.service entered failed state.
```

If I edit the python file and insert a simple `time.sleep(10)` at the very beginning it waits 10 seconds and then happily runs as it should.

Apparently when it's started the network is not *yet* available, despite the dependency on `network-online.target`. How can I make sure that it's only started when the network is really really up and configured?

I'm running it on Raspbian 8 Jessie with systemd 215-17+deb8u7.

Comment: Are you using NetworkManager or something? Could you check is you have anything in `/etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/` ?

Comment: @Bigon I don't think I'm using Network Manager. I don't have any `network-online.target.wants` dirs anywhere on the system (checked /etc, /usr and /var). Perhaps `network-online` returns before dhcpcd is finished? But what's the point of network-online then...

Comment: In jessie I think that the `ifupdown` package is not really well integrated systemd, you should try to update to the backported version of it (version 0.8.13~bpo8+1). Not sure how to do that with raspbian. The easiest would be to upgrade to stretch I would say

Comment: Thanks @Bigon I will try with the newest Raspbian and see if it's any better.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem on Ubuntu 20, leading to very confusing issues (e.g., NFS automounter randomly failing to work): the network was actually online, but DNS support was not available yet. To ensure DNS support, add `systemd-resolved.service` to the `After` and `Wants` entries.